# Updating record in after trigger is not recommended. But, is there any other better solution for my Scenario?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on a custom rule engine (A solution similar to Salesforce workflows). 
Solution allows storing complex criteria using custom objects and process these criteria using a trigger(before trigger by now) to execute field updates.

A sample rule could be:

```
if(ObjectA.ObjectB__r.ObjectC__r.ObjectD__r.Name='ABC')
ObjectA.FieldA='XYZ'
```

As can be noticed I am traversing n level from the object on which rule is defined. I use SOQL similar to

```
[Select ObjectA.ObjectB__r.ObjectC__r.ObjectD__r.Name from ObjectA ]
```

to evaluate rules. Problem is that before trigger will never give me values from relations as value is not yet committed into database. Things will work if I use a after trigger but that will raise another DML for field updates and I have to end up with using some static variables for recursion control .

What would be a recommended solution for this problem ?

Comment: Why dont you retrive the rules via formulas on object a  then you can easily access the rules on first level.

Comment: another suggestion may be to use queueable method to perform an update in future, not in this context

Comment: @erkan çipil:In the application it would be user who defines the rule and its up to him what he will choose as rule or field update. Formulas are rigid definition and can not be changed with every rule criteria that user enters.  Similar to Salesforce workflows no one knows what user will choose as criteria or

Comment: @kurunve: queueable/future methods will consume daily async apex  limit. Further user would always need to refresh page to see resultant field updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over your inserted records and store all ObjectB__c in a set. Then query on ObjectB__c and populate a map as below.

```
map<ObjectB.Id, ObjectB> mapOfObjectB = new map<ObjectB.Id, ObjectB>();
for(ObjectB obj  : [Select ObjectB.ObjectC__r.ObjectD__r.Name 
                      from ObjectB where Id IN : setOfObjectB]) 
{
   mapOfObjectB.put(obj.Id, obj );  
}
```

You can use this map later to check for your scenario

```
if(mapOfObjectB != null && mapOfObjectB.containsKey(ObjectA.ObjectB__c) 
       && mapOfObjectB.get(ObjectA.ObjectB__c).ObjectC__r.ObjectD__r.Name ='ABC')
{
  //your code
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have already tried this approach. The drawback is we will end up using one SOQL per relation. In normal scenarios there could be n number of fields on a object which are either master detail or lookup. By using this approach we need to have same number of additional SOQL in trigger as the number of relationship on object.